# enable button to load data on click until scroll bar is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am loading data on page and using infinite scroll to load more data as the user scrolls (default 20 items on page load. But depending on the screen resolution like 1080 the page loads and the vertical scroll bar is not visible or active for the user to scroll. I added a button for the user to click to load more and as they scroll that load button will hide.

**Problem:** on page load if a vertical scroll is active or visible how can i hide the button from the start rather then having to scroll the first time for it to hide. Also how can i keep the load button visible until a vertical bar is active.

**div/button:**

```
<div id="loadUsers" class="btn" data-bind="click: Next" style="position:fixed; width:auto; height:20px; padding:5px; bottom:10px; ">
    Load more users...
</div>
```

**knockout Next method**

```
Next = function () {
        var _page = $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage() + 1;
        $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage(_page);
        $.views.Roster.GetPage(_page);
    };
```

**hide load button once scrolling is enabled**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#main').scroll(function () {
            $('#loadUsers').hide()
            var div = $(this);
            if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height()) {
               Next();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this function you can know if the vertical scrollbar is active :

```
var isVBActive = function(){
    return ($(document).height() > window.innerHeight);
}
```

And with the [resize event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) can hide or show the button :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(isVBActive())
        $('#button').hide();
    else
        $('#button').show();
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This has helped a lot and i altered it to fit my layout of divs so i had: `$('content').height() < $('main').height()` and i went directly to loading the next set rather than having the user click on a button which they might not notice at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

visible binding:-

```
<div id="loadUsers" class="btn" data-bind="click: Next, visible: displayBtn()" style="display:none; ">
Load more users...
</div>
```

Script:-

```
self.displayBtn= function(){
  return ($(document).height() < window.innerHeight);
 }
```

Comment: so if the document height is less then my ('#main') innerHeight then there is a scroll and my button will be invisible?